# Is there a way of forcing build order between Android ndk static libraries?

Tags: android, android-ndk

We have a fairly large project, building for Windows, Android and iOS and I am trying to parallelize the android build. For historic reasons, during build all the headers are exported to a single directory and their include paths are also based on this single directory. This means that if a module A is dependent on module B, then it expects module B to have copied out its own headers.

According to the NDK documentation, the NDK make script ignores dependencies between static libraries, except for determining transitive dependencies for dynamic libraries, but since we only build static libraries, this doesn't help us.

I thought I could use `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` to export an apropriate path, and it would work, except some of the modules export the headers under different path than the headers are present in the repository.

*Visual Aid:*

```
.
|-- Output
|   |-- Android
|       |-- includes/Foo/Bar
|-- Foo
|   |-- Bar
|   |   |-- Android
|   |   |   |-- stuff.h
|   |   |-- Windows
|   |   |   |-- stuff.h
...
```

A file `qux.cpp` would include header `stuff.h` as `#include <Foo/Bar/stuff.h>`, which works once `stuff.h` is in the `Output` folder, but cannot work while `stuff.h` is in `Foo/Bar/Android`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, **ndk-build** is a wrapper around GNU make. This gives you the power to enforce dependencies.

Here we will abuse the PCH feature of **ndk-build**. If you use PCH in your library, you need a different workaround.

Assume that we have two static libraries, and **libS2.a** should be compiled after **libS1.a**. You will make few modifications to your **Android.mk** file:

```
…
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := S1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := …
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)              # builds libS1.a

FIRST_LIBRARY := $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE)       #### added #1

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := S2
LOCAL_PCH       := pch.h                     #### added #2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := …
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)              # builds libS2.a

$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_PCH): $(FIRST_LIBRARY) #### added #3
    touch $@                                 #### added #4, starts with TAB
```

As you see, we only added 4 lines. Don't miss the TAB character before `touch`.

For this trick to work, it is important that first library is placed *before* the second.

Comment: I have tried this and I get an error saying that there is no rule to make target `...../dummy.h` needed by `...../dummy.precompiled.h.gch`.

Comment: Most likely, you misplaced the third added line. It should go immediately after `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)` for **S2**. If the error persists, then post your Android.mk file (best, via http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Ok, that seems to have worked for the test module, now I just have to fixup the remaining 20 :-). Why does the PCH target have to be right behind `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY`?

Comment: *Why does the PCH target have to be right behind BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY?* well, not necessarily. But you must keep track of $(LOCAL_PATH) and $(LOCAL_PCH) for each library, and the easiest setup is to put this statement before they are changed by some other part of your Android.mk

Comment: D'oh! Originally I had it behind a conditional include, that just happened to be included in the build target I was testing with. (Guess it was better to find it now rather than later.)

Comment: This did indeed work. I would however like to add that ndk-build likes to create highly nested folder structure for the PCH files. I actually managed to run out of the windows path limit.

Comment: how can LOCAL_BUILD_MODULE can be dependent on LOCAL_MODULE? can anyone please help.

Comment: `LOCAL_MODULE` is a string you set in **Android.mk**. `LOCAL_BUILD_MODULE` is a string that NDK generates which represents the actual target (e.g. `libS1.a`). It's not clear what dependency you want to introduce here.